# Corrupted powerpoint pptx generated using openxml C#

Tags: c#, powerpoint, openxml

I am getting the following error while opening the powerpoint file, generated using open xml. I compared the xml of repaired file and corrupted file, it seems to be the same. Can you please help

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

I used the sample code from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc850834.aspx). If you run this code, it works fine. However, if we change this part:

```
   bodyShape.TextBody = new TextBody(new Drawing.BodyProperties(),
                        new Drawing.ListStyle(),
                        new Drawing.Paragraph(new Drawing.Run(new Drawing.Text() { Text = text }));
```

It creates the corrupt file.

[image: Error while opening the pptx]

Comment: Does it happen with any ppt you create? If so could you upload a corrupt and repaired version? Maybe there is some encoding difference
How did you compare these files?

Comment: I renamed the file to .zip, then extracted the xml. Compared each xml file. I will upload both the files. How to upload files here, cant find the option

Comment: Added links to the files. It will be available for 48 hours only

Comment: If use extract the file (after renaming them to .zip), you can use winmerge to compare the content.
You'll see some difference:
in [content_types].xml the repaired version has  standalone="yes"?> in the first row
And in docProps/app.xml the counters have different values.

Comment: How to fix the counters?

Comment: The number of pages and number of words are not correct. I didn't ever use the library you mention, vl but you could check the site of the developer.

Comment: Yes, I checked the difference. Addin more details to the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
                string _DescripcionSuperior = "Hello World";

                bodyShape.TextBody = new P.TextBody(new Drawing.BodyProperties(),
                             new Drawing.ListStyle(),
                             new Drawing.Paragraph(new Drawing.Run(
                                 new Drawing.RunProperties() { Language = "es-MX", FontSize = 1000, Dirty = false, Bold = false },
                                 new Drawing.Text(_DescripcionSuperior)
                                 )));
```